# Programmatically creating Typescript Declarations from API Data

Tags: typescript

Edit, I found this: https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/dts-dom. I think it'll work.

I'm writing some web components that interact with some data in the DOM that is passed down to my web component. The software I'm working with provides a single Object passed into the my component's attribute as a JSON string, which Lit Element parses and gives me an object. I want to have type safety on this property. There are many applications, and I can use the API to get information about what fields each application could provide to this attribute.

I know the domain any particular component is being developed for, and I can use the API of the software I'm working with to give me a list of fields, and their possible values, of the object that will be passed into my component. This obviously won't happen at runtime, but before I begin development.

I want to write a simple script that will get the field details from the API, parse the response, and output a `.d.ts` file to consume during development of the web components.

For Example, the API may respond

```json
{
  "applicationId": "js09jsd09js",
  "applicationName": "My Particular Application",
  "fields": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "fieldName": "name",
      "fieldDescription": "Name of the Owner"
    },
    {
      "type": "number",
      "fieldName": "phone number",
      "fieldDescription": "Owner's Phone Number",
    },
    {
      "type": "multiselect",
      "fieldName": "gender",
      "fieldDescription": "Owner's Gender",
      "values": [
        {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "Male"
        },
        {
          "type": "string",
          "value": "Female"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

and the script I will create will output this:

```js
interface MyParticularApplicationRecord {
  applicationId: string;
  applicationName: string;
  fields: {
    name: string;
    'phone number': number;
    gender: 'Male' | 'Female';
  }
}
// in which I use this elsewhere to define the property type.
const people: Array<MyParticularApplicationRecord.fields> = [...] // <-- possible of people, typesafe.
```

There, of course, are some more complex field types that my application supports, and I can create some generic types for it to work with to help building.

Comment: Have you tried anything? StackOverflow is typically used for questions about errors that have been run into, and very rarely will people ever just write something to solve your specific problem.

Comment: Well I was looking for a library  to work with. I would love to have errors to work with.
At any rate, someone on reddit gave me this. https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/dts-dom

Comment: Your JSON does not match your interface example. Actually, your JSON isn't valid, the last `}` should be a `]`